# cassandra batch update does not perform

Tags: cassandra, cql

We have 2 cassandra datacenters 3 nodes in each.

After make the following queries one after another the results are inconsistent:

```
BEGIN BATCH 
UPDATE t1 set units - {'u1'} where location = 'loc1';
UPDATE t1 set units - {'u1'} where location = 'loc2';
UPDATE t1 set units - {'u1'} where location = 'loc3';
...
UPDATE t1 set units - {'u1'} where location = 'loc200';
APPLY BATCH;
```

and

```
BEGIN BATCH 
UPDATE t1 set units + {'u1'} where location = 'loc100';
UPDATE t1 set units + {'u1'} where location = 'loc101';
UPDATE t1 set units + {'u1'} where location = 'loc102';
...
UPDATE t1 set units + {'u1'} where location = 'loc200';
APPLY BATCH;
```

sometimes it performs as needed and the result is that 'u1' is added to sets for rows with location 101-200, sometimes nothing happens and sometimes only part of the range is set (like only locations 101-123).

Why can batch queries fail without an exception and why aren't they consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the nodes time was out of sync.